# What does aura: component controller here mean?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura

Where is controller ="PatientAccProgCase_ListController" coming from in the code below which is part of the aura component's .cmp?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" 
                controller="PatientAccProgCase_ListController">
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply means there is an Apex class named `PatientAccProgCase_ListController` that contains methods used by this component. This is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:component/documentation).

> The server-side controller class for the component in the format `namespace.myController` or `myController` if using the default namespace.